# Django update by F() with log and square, a float needed

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have model,

```
class Data(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField()
    b = models.IntegerField()
    c = models.IntegerField()
    d = models.IntegerField()
    e = models.IntegerField()
    f = models.IntegerField()
    x = models.Decimalfield(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
    y = models.Decimalfield(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
```

now i have to update fields x and y for each row by formula:

```
x = 100 * b + ( c/log(d*e)) + e^2*f
y = 100 * b + ( c*log(d/e)) + e^2/f
```

i don't know how to do it, using django F such that,
x & y get stored as fomated data where b,c,d,e,f are int's.
and use math function with F() in django

Comment: How are you getting the input?

Comment: so first time i will upload csv/exel to input a,b,c,d,e,f and after that those weights can be variable not 100 only for example w1 may be 200 or 300...so actual formula is like ,x = w1 * b + ( c/log(d*e)) + e^2*f, w1 will be user specific on update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#query-expressions):

> Django supports the use of addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and modulo arithmetic with F() objects, both with constants and with other F() objects.

Logarithms aren't a supported operation, so there's no way to get `log(d*e)` into an update call.  You'll have to do that in Python at some point, or by using a [direct SQL update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).  Or by using a database view containing `LOG(d)` and `LOG(e)` as columns instead of the default table.

The rest of it you can do:

```
Data.objects.update(x=(F('b') * 100 + F('e') * F('e') * F('f')), y=(F('b') + (F('e') * F('e')) / F('f'))
```

I understand that that doesn't help much without the logarithms, but I'm including it to demonstrate the use of the arithmetic on F objects.